# How to see if a string only contains certain characters, and if they do, return True, else return False: Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, binary

For python 3.4.1, how would you go about finding if certain characters are in your string? I tried doing it this way:

```
def isItBinary(myString):
    for ele in myString:
        if ele == '1' or if ele == '0':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem with this code is that if I type isItBinary('102'), it will return True. I just want it to return True if and only if it contains '1' or '0'.

Comment: The problem with your current code is that it just checks the first condition, as the functions ends at the `return`.

Comment: Would i have to use in the range(myString)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the `all` function.

```
def isItBinary(myString):
    return all(x in ('0', '1') for x in myString)
```

The `x in ('0', '1')` checks that the character in `x` is either '0' or '1'.

Comment: I've never been a fan of that since it also matches '01'. In this case it's not a possibility so '01' works, but I like the clarity of explicitly showing I only want to match '0' or '1'.

Comment: could your provide any input that would produce a wrong result with `x in '01'`?

Comment: Could you explain what the x means?

Comment: As I said, in this case '01' works. But in the case that you wanted (for example) a 'y' or 'n' from `raw_input`, `x in 'yn'` could potentially also match the string 'yn' which would not be the intent of the code. Because of this gotcha, I prefer to use the `tuple` form in general to increase clarity of what it is I want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply `isitBinary` on multiple characters, since as the way you wrote it it will return as soon as the first character is checked.

A simple way to do what you want would be:

```
def binaryChar(myCharacter):
    return myCharacter == '1' or myCharacter == '0'
```

and then apply it to all of the chars in a string, like this:

```
def isItBinary(myString):  
    return all(binaryChar(c) for c in myString)
```

Of course, these can be simplified in a more readable way:

```
def isItBinary(myString):
    return all(c in '01' for c in myString)
```

or via a lambda function:

```
isItBinary = lambda myString: all(c in '01' for c in myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program was returning the value as soon as the first character was encountered, you were not even iterating over the whole string. This approach below checks if the condition is invalid at any point, returns `False` otherwise iterates the whole string and returns `True`.

```
def isItBinary(myString):
    for ele in myString:
        if not ele in ("0","1"):
            return False
    return True


print isItBinary("102")
>>> False
print isItBinary("101")
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets:

```
def is_it_binary(s):
    return not (set(s) - set("01"))
```

If the set constructed from the string contains any characters not in the second set the subtraction gives a non-empty set. Otherwise if it contains only the characters in the second set you get an empty set which the `not` flips to `True`.

Alternatively just:

```
def is_it_binary(s):
    allowed = set("01")
    return all(c in allowed for c in s)
```

which has the advantage of short-circuiting (i.e. it bombs out as soon as an invalid character is found).